# Python Pandas: Get row by median value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the row of the median value for a column.

I'm using data.median() to get the median value for 'column'.

```
id                 30444.5
someProperty           3.0
numberOfItems          0.0
column                70.0
```

And data.median()['column'] is subsequently:

```
data.median()['performance']
>>> 70.0
```

How can get the row or index of the median value? 
Is there anything similar to idxmax / idxmin?

I tried filtering but it's not reliable in cases multiple rows have the same value.

Thanks!

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411507/get-corresponding-index-of-median

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be just : `data[data.performance==data.median()['performance']]`.

Comment: That's pretty good, though it does return a set of results. In that case, all values where 'performance' == 70.

Comment: Yes, I was about to point that out. You may want to randomly pick one out of multiple matches, instead of always picking out the first or the last one, to avoid potential bias. Especially so with time series data.

Comment: This is not true in the case that the dataset is with even number of values. Than the median would be the average between the two middle values and it will not be in the dataset. Hence,Series([], dtype: float32)

Comment: @layser for what you described one should *not* get a match, exactly as result. As to finding the value index *closest* to the median, that's a different question

Comment: I'm not sure this works if there are an odd number of elements (no individual element will equal the median because the median is the average of two elements).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rank` and `idxmin` and apply it to each column:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def get_median_index(d):
    ranks = d.rank(pct=True)
    close_to_median = abs(ranks - 0.5)
    return close_to_median.idxmin()
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(13, 4))
df
```

```
    0           1           2           3
0   0.919681    -0.934712   1.636177    -1.241359
1   -1.198866   1.168437    1.044017    -2.487849
2   1.159440    -1.764668   -0.470982   1.173863
3   -0.055529   0.406662    0.272882    -0.318382
4   -0.632588   0.451147    -0.181522   -0.145296
5   1.180336    -0.768991   0.708926    -1.023846
6   -0.059708   0.605231    1.102273    1.201167
7   0.017064    -0.091870   0.256800    -0.219130
8   -0.333725   -0.170327   -1.725664   -0.295963
9   0.802023    0.163209    1.853383    -0.122511
10  0.650980    -0.386218   -0.170424   1.569529
11  0.678288    -0.006816   0.388679    -0.117963
12  1.640222    1.608097    1.779814    1.028625
```

```py
df.apply(get_median_index, 0)
```

```
0    7
1    7
2    3
3    4
```