# Get corresponding index of median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, median

I have a pandas dataframe with one column and I would like to know the index of the median. That is, I determine the median this way:

df.median()

This gives me the median value, but I would like to know the index of that row. Is it possible to determine this? For a list with uneven length I could search for the index with that value but for even list lengths this is not going to work. Can someone help?

This question was asked in another post, where the answer was basically to search for rows which have the same value as the median. But like I said, that will not work for a list of even length.

Below is a Min Example (I have included the suggestion by Wen below):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 1), columns=list('A'))
df.median()
df.loc[df[0]==df[0].median()]

Out[120]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.col==df.col.median()]`

Comment: Thank you Wen. I get this error using that command: 
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: Replace col to your column names.

Comment: Oh I see. But I am not exactly sure what the column name is. Using:
df.columns.values
I get 
array([0], dtype=int64)

Comment: Then df.loc[df[0]==df[0].median()]

Comment: I tried that and I get : 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []

Comment: This is all I can do , Without seeing the data ..

Comment: Isn't your command searching for rows with the same value as the median? Isn't that impossible for a list of even length?

Comment: Because then, the median becomes the average of the two observations in the middle. And this value is not part of the list

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124418/python-pandas-get-row-by-median-value/64126391#64126391

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Wen's answer for dataframes of odd length.

For dataframes of even length, the question does not really make sense. As you have pointed out the median does not exist in the dataframe. However, you can sort the dataframe by your column of interest and then find the indices for the two "median" values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 1), columns=list('A'))
df.median()

df.loc[df['A']==df['A'].median()]

df.sort_values(by='A', inplace=True)

df[df['A'] > df['A'].median()].iloc[0]
df[df['A'] < df['A'].median()].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right of course, for the even length the median is not in the dataframe. This is a great alternative solution. That works for me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Computing the median is costly, when you have already sorted the DataFrame you could just pick the median entry `df.iloc[int(len(df)/2)]` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use the [quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) function (which convieniently defaults to 0.5, i.e. the median) and set the `interpolation` argument so that it doesn't try to split the midpoints on a DataFrame of even length.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1), columns=['A'])


# row nearest to midpoint 
df[df['A']==df['A'].quantile(interpolation='nearest')]

# just below the midpoint
df[df['A']==df['A'].quantile(interpolation='lower')]

# just above the midpoint
df[df['A']==df['A'].quantile(interpolation='higher')]
```